# Submitting a database for a project

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We were required to build a database using MySQL workbench. I've got the database built and it works great, but I don't know how to submit it. Is there a .database file or something that I can submit?

Comment: You mean to export your sql file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to export your database to a folder location.

Click on Manage Import/Export on the right (when you have your Home tab selected). Select the database you want to save, enter your password and whatever, select Export to Disk, select your database and all the tables you want to save, and click on Export to Self-Contained File and enter in the folder location you want, and your database file should be in there. The database file will have an .sql extension though.

Comment: Ok, that's what I've done but I was not sure if there was an actual database file that I could submit. Cheers!